# Is Concept of Encapsulation Violated here?

Tags: c++, oop, encapsulation

```
#include<iostream>

class A {
public:
  int a;
protected:
  void func() {
  std::cout<<"protected member"<<endl;
  }
};

class B:public A
{
public:
  using A::func;  //Isn't this violation of encapsulation?
};

int main(){
B b;
b.func();
return 0;
}
```

Why the above code runs successfully?

Does it not violate the concept of Encapsulation?

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What does "encapsulation" mean?

Comment: It's up to the designer of B to decide what interface to use, including providing access to protected members of A.

Comment: Why would the above code not run successfully? Why would it violate the concept of Encapsulation? Since it _doesn't_, you need to explain to us your mistaken belief, before we can correct it.

Comment: I see that you have also posted questions about Java. C++ and Java have lots of differences when it comes to the "concepts" of programming. They are very different languages in many ways. This is one of those.

Comment: So it turns out that I need not explicitly inherit the protected members like this ` class B : protected A` . Correct me if I am still wrong.

Comment: Protected inheritance only means that the public members of A will also be protected in B. Private inheritance means that *everything* will be private in B. Whatever you do, all members of A will also be members of B.

Comment: Thanks alot for clearing my misconceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and I think it highlights an important and often-overlooked aspect of encapsulation in c++.

My answer is that "yes, encapsulation has been violated, but not where you think". The actual violation was in declaring the method to be `protected` in the first place.

Your code demonstrates nicely the problem with the protected relationship with subclasses... they can de-protect you with ease. Another way of saying this is that if you're going to make a member `protected`, you may as well make it `public` because in reality `protected` is `public` if your subclasses want it to be.

What does this mean in practice?

It means that if you make a member function `protected`, it is forever part of your class's interface. Therefore you must treat is as seriously as you would any other public member function and indeed *as if it were* a public member function.

Which is to say that it should be as stateless as possible, with as few preconditions as possible and should you change the implementation, the *logical effect on the object as a whole* must remain unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, this is the explanation I wanted.

Comment: Indeed. Declaring implementation details as `protected` seems to be a common beginners' mistake. I remember making it myself when I was new at C++. As years of experience would later show, `protected` is rarely useful at all. Almost all members should be `public` or `private`.

Answer (score 2):

The example that you are showing is *not* a violation of encapsulation, because subclasses are allowed to add public members on top of what they inherit, and they also are allowed to access protected members that they inherit.

In your case, `B`, a subclass of `A`, decided to add a new member function called `func`, whose implementation happens to consist of a single invocation of `A::func`.

Generally, `protected` members should be regarded part of *interface* of your class, along with its `public` members. Despite the fact that their visibility is limited to subclasses, protected members are not part of the class *implementation*, because any change to protected members naming or semantics need to be coordinated with changes to all subclasses of the class.

Comment: What about the `func()` being protected?

Comment: @ShubhamBatra: What about it? `protected` literally means that derived classes have access to that symbol, so there's no problem. Did you confuse `protected` for `private`?

Comment: @ShubhamBatra Only `A::func()` is protected; `B::func()` is not protected  by an explicit choice of the designer of class `B`.

Comment: @ShubhamBatra - `B` could just as well have added `void another_func() { func(); }`. What's the difference?